# AWS Glue Catalog API: Parameters field in metadata of different structures

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

AWS Glue Data Catalog is composed of different structures, e.g. 
[Database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-databases.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-databases-Database), 
[Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-tables-Table), 
[Partition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions-Partition), 
[Column](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-tables-Column) etc. Haven't looked through every one of them, but it seems that `Parameters` fields (a map array of key-value pairs) is present in all of them. I have noticed that if table was created by a [crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html) then we can see something like:

```
{
    "CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion": "1.0",
    "CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion": "1.0",
    "UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER": "some-crawler-name",
    "averageRecordSize": "12",
    "classification": "parquet",
    "compressionType": "none",
    "objectCount": "123",
    "recordCount": "1234567",
    "sizeKey": "1234567890",
    "typeOfData": "file"
}
```

for `Table["Parameters"]` as well as `Table["StorageDescriptor"]["Parameters"]`. If our table has partitions, then each one of them would have the same dictionary, but with different values for **averageRecordSize**, **objectCount**, **recordCount**, **sizeKey**. After summing them up we end up with the same values as in `Table["Parameters"]`. All of it makes sense, and I guess these values determine crawlers' logic when we want to re-run it on demand or on schedule.

Instead of using crawlers, I manage multiple AWS Glue catalogs manually with [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html) and [airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/). For example, I could copy partitions definition from `db_1.table_1` in catalog *12345* into `db_2.table_2` in catalog *6789*, or define additional meta-parameters in `table_1`. However, this **Parameters** field is still quite a mystery to me and I couldn't find any sort of documentation related to it.

It looks like some keys, e.g. `recordCount`, are reserved for internal use within AWS Glue (although they can be defined manually).

1. Do other services (especially Athena) use them as well?
2. Where can I find a list of such keys and their meaning, so that my keys wouldn't interfere?
3. Docs mention that these key-value pairs define properties associated with the table and some restrictions:

   > 1. Each key is a Key string, not less than 1 or more than 255 bytes long, matching the Single-line string pattern.
   > 2. Each value is a UTF-8 string, not more than 512000 bytes long.

   Is there any restriction on how many keys can `Parameters` field contain? Does number of these key-value pairs affect performance when you query data?
4. How important is it to keep `Parameters` field in sync for table, partition and their storage descriptors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, e.g. Redshift spectrum uses it to optimize query plan - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html#r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE-parameters
2. Unfortunately, there is no complete document explaining all TBLPROPERTIES.

   - But you may find few in above Rdshift Spectrum link.
   - You may run following sql query in athena to get TBLPROPERTIES used for a given table:`SHOW TBLPROPERTIES <table_name>`
   - You may also check HIVE doc as presto is based on HIVE - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ManagedandExternalTables . Note that not all properties are applicable in Athena.
3. I don't think it impacts performance negatively. Internal properties are usually used for certain activities e.g. `crawled_by` is used by Glue , `numRows` is used by Athena/Redshift, `has_encrypted_data` is used to check if s3 data is encrypted or not and so on.
4. It is important to keep in sync as these properties are used to manage table and queries on it efficiently. Certain properties e.g. `skip.header.line.count=2` can skip first two rows and will not treat as data rows.

Comment: If the intention is to create the table via DDL in Athena. But, to get there, we manually created a crawler first, then ran "Generate table DDL" in Athena and copied the DDL to create the table via DDL in Athena....I assume, we won't need these properties?

"CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion": "1.0",
    "CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion": "1.0",
    "UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER": "some-crawler-name",
    "averageRecordSize": "12",
    "UpdatedByJobRun": "some-crawler-jobid"